# jQuery hide - div's,p,a,li, etc

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-get-contents

I have this code and jquery function for hide HTML elements when press right click, but why dont work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("mousedown", "div, p, img, span, a", function () { 
    if (event.which === 3)
       $(this).hide();
});
</script>
<?php

$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;

echo $data;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the param event, also you are using jQuery 1.3.2, which does not have the `.on` function yet, you need at least 1.7.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("mousedown", "div, p, img, span, a", function (event) { 
    if (event.which === 3)
       $(this).hide();
});
</script>
<?php

$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;

echo $data;

?>
```

Please fix this list:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/css/css_style.aspFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/css/fb_css_style.cssFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/scripts/swfobject.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/scripts/countdown/jquery.countdown.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/scripts/lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/scripts/jqtransform/jqtransform.cssFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/scripts/lightbox/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.cssFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://pluspon.com/scripts/jqtransform/jquery.jqtransform.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/kupime_world/bosna_flag.jpg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/kupime_world/srb_113359.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/images/rs/logo_small.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/kupime_world/slo_113425.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_2_235532.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/gal1_17290.jpg.axd?width=144&height=96&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_2_16323.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/site_banners/kako_funkcionise_kupime_142020.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_1_172429.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/site_banners/kupime_com_nacin_placanja11_164124.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/site_banners/kupime-home-desni-box-srbija_123628.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_0841.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/images/rs/logo_programa.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/gal_2_172910.jpg.axd?width=144&height=96&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/glavna_1_173127.jpg.axd?width=441 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_103623.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_191212.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_174731.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/kupime_world/hun_133823.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_03932.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/kupime_world/cro_113411.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/images/scrollHeadLetterTop.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/gal_3_172929.jpg.axd?width=144&height=96&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_st_171818.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_1_175010.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/images/rss.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_1_231525.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_231142.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/images/fb.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/images/twitter.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://pluspon.com/upload/oglas/mala_235111.jpg.axd?width=204&height=140&crop=auto 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.kupime.com/images/logo.png.axd?width=193&height=154 404 (Not Found)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.kupime.com/index.asp?cmd=get_offer_coupons&offer_id=954. Origin http://pluspon.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: you should update your code to show us what you tried.  I went to your link but the popup wouldn't let me try anything.

Comment: yes but this popup is an Div and right click on them must hide !

Comment: but I'm using <base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /> to change pluspon domain with $url - for that.

Comment: OK, i'm see this but how to fix that?

Comment: i was thinking that base tag fix that but seems like not good

Comment: Is there any way to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your syntax to be off, api.jquery.com/mousedown .mousedown() event. Try selecting the elements by $('div, p, img, span, a').mousedown(function(){});

You are also referencing event in your "mousedown" function, where event is not defined.

```
$('div, p, img, span, a').mousedown(function()
{
    $(this).hide();
})
```

And to reshow.

```
$('div, p, img, span, a').mouseup(function()
{
    $(this).show();
});
```

For yours

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('div, p, img, span, a').bind("mousedown", function(e)
    {
        if (e.which === 3)
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});   
</script>
<?php

$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;

echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: How to implement that on my function I post

Comment: becouse this work very strange how I can change background on :hover to know what element is hide

Comment: @thescientist - I voted yours up, I propose my answer as an alternative to using 1.7 + for his problem.

Comment: @user1094631 - not sure I understand what you mean `becouse this work very strange how I can change background on :hover to know what element is hide`

Comment: right click on popup (which is an DIV) must hide popup with this but seems like doesnt work

Comment: try modifying the `$(this).hide();` to an alert to verify the event is wired up. You may be wiring the event up before the element exists in the DOM.

Comment: popup is: <div id="active_banner_wrap">
 and when click nothing happends

Comment: The javascript that is literally `$(this).hide();` change to `alert('test');`. When you click you should receive the alert that tells you the event is wired up. When I navigated to the page, `<div id="active_banner_wrap">` looks like its behind the lightbox item. It may not receive the right click